# What does "-t" in "bight" mean?

Tags: etymology, morphology

Wiktionary says, that "-t" in "bight" is a [variant of](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-t#Etymology_3) "-th" suffix (bight = bought = bough + t) but I think, that "-t" in "bight" is an Old English [past participle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-t#Etymology_1) ending of "bow". Is my hypothesis reasonable?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "mean" here. Even if it once started out like the -t in *bent* long ago, It's no longer perceived as a morpheme, so a sub-lexical unit of language carrying meaning of its own.

Comment: 3 things: 1) WIktionary is often unreliable. 2) Use [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bight) as a first pass. 3) I don't see a '-th' in the variants you give. 3)

Comment: @Mitch The th variants are perfectly cromulent: the t in _height_ and _theft_ is the same as the th in _width_ and _birth_. Etymonline is generally not really more reliable than Wiktionary for PG and PIE etymology (Wiktionary is editable by anyone, which makes it more fragile, but also more up to date; Etymonline is more vetted, but primarily sourced from the OED whose etymologies are often old and in need of updating). Both require a fair amount of knowledge of the subject in order to be able to separate the wheat from the chaff.

Answer (score 4):

### No, that is not possible

As you’ve already discovered, the verb *bow* and the noun *bight* both derive from the Proto-Indo-European (verbal) root [**bʰeu̯gʰ-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/b%CA%B0ewg%CA%B0-) ‘bend, curve’, but they are different formations.

#### The suffixes

Wiktionary is correct that the suffix in *bight* is the *-t* which is an alternative form of *-th*. This suffix was in Proto-Germanic **-þiz*, inherited from PIE **-ti-s* (where **-s* is the nominative singular masculine ending, so the suffix itself is **-ti-*). These **-ti-* stems are exceedingly common in PIE, and they generally form abstract nouns from verbal roots.

The past participle suffix, on the other hand, was in PIE **-tó-s*, in Germanic **-þaz* alternating with **-taz* in the same way that **-tiz* and **-þiz* alternated depending on the preceding sound. The past participle, if formed to the same root, would have been ***buhtaz* in PG, but as it happens, I don’t think that form existed. The verb **beugana-* ‘bow, bend’ is a strong verb in Germanic, and as such, it forms its past participle with the other inherited past participle suffix, **-naz* (from PIE **-nó-s*).

There is a different verb from a PIE root which is either homophonic or actually just the same root, namely PG [**būgjana-* ‘deal, buy’](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/bugjan%C4%85) – and that verb is weak and forms its past participle with the dental suffix: **buhtaz*, the direct ancestor of *bought* in current English.

#### How the suffixes develop after Proto-Germanic

This indicates (indirectly, but also correctly, I can tell you) that PG **buhtiz* and **buhtaz* develop differently later on.

They do so because of two roughly opposite developments: [i-mutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-mutation), whereby a vowel develops into a higher, more fronted version of itself if there is an /i/ in the following syllable; and [a-mutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_a-mutation), whereby a vowel develops into a lower, vowel if there is an /a/ in the following syllable.

For the vowel /u/ in Germanic languages, this means a development from /u/ to /y/ (as in French *une*) with i-mutation, and a development from /u/ to /o/ with a-mutation. The sound /y/ existed in Old English, but was lost in Middle English when it merged with /i/, so for present-day English purposes, you could say that i-mutation turned /u/ into /i/.

The West Germanic languages all lost final consonants, then all unstressed final syllables very early on – before Old English – but i- and a-mutation had already happened by that time, and their results remained in place after the final syllables that caused them were lost. That means our two words here developed thus:

- **buhtiz* first became **byhtiz*, then **byhti*, then *byht* (the actual word as attested in Old English), and then in Middle English *biht* (also spelt *biȝt* and half a dozen other ways) and in Modern English *bight*
- **buhtaz* first became **bohtaz*, then **bohta*, then *boht* (the Old English form). The sequence /oht/ was somewhat labile and didn’t develop very regularly during the [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift); in most cases, as in this case, it ended up as /ɔːt/ in Modern English

#### tl;dr / Conclusion

As should be clear now, *bight* **cannot** come from any form with an inherited past participle suffix (PIE **-tó-s*, PG **-þaz/-taz*, Eng. _-t/-ed) because it shows the clear effect of i-mutation, which the past participle suffix does not cause. It fits instead with the abstract noun suffix (PIE **-ti-s*, PG **-þiz/-tiz*, Eng. *-th/-t*), which has an /i/ in it and does cause i-mutation.

Conversely, the form *bought* does fit with an inherited past participle suffix because it shows the effect of a-mutation, which the abstract noun suffix does not cause.

Comment: In case you haven't seen it yet [the OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/18881) mentions as cognates not only Danish *bugt* but also “Old Icelandic” (Norse?)  *‑bót* (in *knés-bót* hollow of the knee) < a derivative formation < the same base as **ʙᴏᴡ** *n*.¹. It also mentions vestiges in some 13th-century toponyms and suggests that one also see Old English *gebyhte* bend, corner, angle

Comment: @tchrist Yes, the Norse forms (and actually also the German forms) don’t display any i-mutation here; if memory serves, this is due to the cluster _*-ht-_, which blocks fronting outside English. A parallel example is _daughter_, which has a form with mutation (_dehter_) in OE, but nowhere else. (Of course, even English eventually chose a non-mutated form as the standard in this word, but it had both.)

Comment: Well, in that case, I think, that "-t" in "bight" is a variant of Proto-Germanic "*-þiz" suffix + bee (bēah).

Comment: @w4zlav No, _bēah_ is Old English, and it’s an inflected verb form (‘I/he bent/bowed’) – at the time when _*-þiz_ existed, _bēah_ did not (it would have been _*baugV-_ at that time). By the time _bēah_ existed, the suffix was just _þ/t_ which wouldn’t cause mutation anymore if productively added, and _ēa_ does not yield ME /i/. Also, _*-þiz_ is a nominalising suffix added to roots, not inflected forms. In fact, in Germanic languages, there aren’t any derivational suffixes at all that are added to inflected verb forms.